# Android Emulator Shows React Native Starter App Instead of Correct App

Tags: react-native

After an attempt to use the `adb` tool to pull an updated sqlite database to my android emulator, I am unable to run my app on that emulator. Instead of showing the main screen of my app, I get the "Welcome to React Native!" demo app. My source code does NOT contain this; all my App.js contains is a definition for a StackNavigator.

Here are the things I have tried in order to fix this:

- Via the AVD console in Android Studio, delete and recreate the image (Nexus 5, Android 6 with Google API)
- Via the same console, use the Wipe Data option to try to reset it to a blank state.
- Various npm commands, such as clean cache.

In addition, when I attempt to run `react-native run-android` from the command line, it usually immediately exits after building the application.

Can anyone give me any idea what I can do just to simply run my app on the emulator?

App source is at https://github.com/fergusonjason/soccerstats if that is any help.

(Yes, I realize this sounds stupid. Why it would replace an app I've been working on for 3 weeks with the react-native starter app is beyond me).

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several things, I ended up forcing a rebuild of index.android.bundle:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

It's possible that I had never staged or committed any updates of this file to the github repo.

Thank you to Aureo Beck for attempting to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your java script bundler is up and running with `react-native start` you can try to reload by running `adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_MENU` in another terminal and pressing `reload` after the Dev Menu shows up in the emulator.

Then be sure to check in your terminal where you ran the start command, if the `Bundling` log shows up. If it doesn't shows up, then perhaps you have another bundler running, which needs to be terminated before you can run your project

Comment: I can be reasonably sure that I don't have a ghost bundler running, as I even rebooted the computer (so no extra process would be running after hours of troubleshooting).

Reloading did nothing. 

It seems to me that there has to be something cached, but I don't know what to do at this point.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the application in the emulator and do a fresh `react-native run-android`

Comment: Yes, I have, with no luck.